# Unable to Get Remote-User value

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, mod-rewrite, http-headers, ajp

Fronting tomcat with Apache Ldap authentication .

I can see through TCP DUMP that my http header sending remote_user:..RICHARD to tomcat.

I have tried Both mod_AJP and mod_HTTP

but can't print the remote_user, through my Restful java spring webservices.
Yes, Tomcatauthentication="false" in server.xml.

Why I can't print REMOTE_USER Please Help.

Comment: How are you using `mod-rewrite`?

Comment: This is how I am using `mod-rewrite`: `RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
        RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%1]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e`   In Apache access_logs I'm able to see the user name printing. But don't know how to capture it in java code. used getHeader(remote-user) and getRemoteUser(). @w3dk

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of thing I would have suggested (apart from the `RequestHeader` part. HTTP headers are usually of the form `Remote-User`. Is the `%{RU}e` expanded?). This is presumably directly in your server config, as opposed to `<Directory>` section or `.htaccess` file? Have you tried accessing the _environment variable_ (`RU`) in your Java code?